# Difference between from .. import and from . import

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between these imports in Python and when would you use these? How many dots "." can we use?

```py
from something import this
from .. import this
from . import this
```

Comment: If you importing from another file in the module, then you use the `.` and `..` to indicate relative directory. You could also do `from ../../.. import something`

Comment: (one dot)`.` is from current directory and (two dots)`..` from upper directory

Comment: Please see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

Imagine we have the following structure:

```
| my_package
| __init__.py
|___ inner_package
    | __init__.py
    | foo.py
    | bar.py
    |___ even_more_inner_package
        | inner_foo.py
        |___ __init__.py
| main.py
```

The first `from something import this` imports from the top application package, meaning that if we wanted to import something from `inner_package` anywhere in our files, we would have to do it like this:

```py
from my_package.inner_package import foo
```

The second and the third import statements are also known as [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/), which works exactly as folders:

The second statement `from .. import something` means "From the upper package, import something". Imagine that we are inside `inner_foo.py`, which is inside `my_package.inner_package.even_more_inner_package`, we can do the following to import `bar.py`:

```py
# This statement goes one package up and looks for bar
from .. import bar
```

The final `from . import something` statements means "From this current package, import something". If we were writing the code from `bar.py` and wanted to import `foo.py` we could use:

```py
from . import foo
```

## Note

You cannot use relative import `from ..` on the top level package. In this example, executing `from .. import my_package` inside `main.py`  will raise an `ImportError`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is better than defining an absolute path?

Comment: It would recommend it, but I personally like the absolutes paths whenever possible though, because I think it is more visual to see the entire packages than just dots everywhere, but its just my  opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is called relative imports. A relative import specifies the resource to be imported relative to the current location—that is, the location where the import statement is.

A single dot means that the module or package referenced is in the same directory as the current location. Two dots mean that it is in the parent directory of the current location—that is, the directory above. Three dots mean that it is in the grandparent directory, and so on.

Assume:

```
└── project
    ├── package1
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   └── module2.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module3.py
        ├── module4.py
        └── subpackage1
            └── module5.py
```

Assume file contents:

```
package1/module2.py contains a function, function1.

package2/__init__.py contains a class, class1.

package2/subpackage1/module5.py contains a function, function2.
```

You can import function1 into the package1/module1.py file this way:

```
from .module2 import function1
```

You can import class1 and function2 into the package2/module3.py file this way:

```
from . import class1
from .subpackage1.module5 import function2
```

A good source: [Absolute vs Relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)